# Sparql to combine list into 1 row's results

Tags: sparql

I've looked at `GROUP_CONCAT`, but it doesn't do what I want.

Lets say I have this data:

```
_:autos325 rdf:first "john";
           rdf:rest _:autos326.
_:autos326 rdf:first "d";
           rdf:rest _:autos327.
_:autos327 rdf:first "rockefeller";
           rdf:rest rdf:nil.
<http://foo.com/ABC> <http://prop/name> _:autos325
```

If I use this SPARQL to read back out the name:

```
SELECT  *  WHERE { <http://foo.com/ABC> <http://prop/name> ?o .
                    ?o rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?foo . }
```

I get the name back, but each part of the name is given as a separate row in the results

If I use `GROUP_CONCAT`, it works until you use a variable as the subject. I can't omit `?s` from the `GROUP BY` or I get a syntax error

```
select ?s  (group_concat(distinct ?foo;separator=", ") as ?names)
WHERE { ?s <http://prop/name> ?o .
                        ?o rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?foo . }
GROUP BY ?s ?foo
```

How can I concatenate the `?foo` results so the entire name is stuffed into one row instead of spread across three result rows ?

Comment: "It doesn't do what I want” why not? Show what you've tried.

Comment: I stated what I tried in the body of the question. I tried GROUP_CONCAT, GROUP BY, etc but the results are still on multiple rows. Do you have a solution or just commenting I should show what I tried

Comment: Please include the SPARQL query where you tried GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: My point was that `GROUP_CONCAT` should normally be the solution to this problem, so if that doesn't do what you want,  you have either a rare corner case, or you did something wrong when you tried. But we don't know what you did because you didn't show.

Comment: Ok, I updated it with what I tried. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are grouping on `?foo`. Change it to:

```
GROUP BY ?s
```

and it should work.

Aggregating operators (such as `COUNT`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, etc) always operate on *groups* of solutions. The groups are defined by the `GROUP BY` clause (if not present, the entire solution counts as a one big group). So having `GROUP BY ?s` basically says: "concatenate the names *per value of `?s`*". But if you also add `?foo` to the `GROUP BY` you're effectively saying: "concatenate the names *per combination of values of  `?s` and `?foo`*". This of course then results in a separate row for each value of `?foo` again, and effectively nothing gets concatenated.

Comment: Yea, that works, but if I have other  triples in the query and try to select them, I get an error saying the select values arent in the GROUP BY. If I group by ?s  , how to I SELECT other variables while also using GROUP_CONCAT ?

Comment: Well that wasn't part of your question, and is really a different case. I suggest you post a followup question to outlines that case in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with a simple case but not with complex queries, since I have to start including other variables in the `GROUP BY`. The correct way was to `GROUP BY` the subject then use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Yes, I'm a newbie to SPARQL :-)

```
SELECT ?s  (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?foo;separator=", ") AS ?names)
WHERE { ?s <http://prop/name> ?o .
        ?o rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?foo . }
GROUP BY ?s
```